# Map key and value initialization from a variable

Tags: c++, dictionary, initialization

I am having hard time initializing a map (both key and value) from variables that are calculated in the code. such as the following example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
map<int, int> order;
order[(a)] = b;
```

I am trying to have the variable a as the key and the variable b as the value. Am I allow to do that ?

Comment: `order[(a)] = b;` is correct (and the parent are superfluous).

Comment: Given that you use the word "initialization", even tag the question as such, you should be aware that strictly speaking, what you are doing is not initialization. The initialization of `order` happens as a result of the declaration `map<int,int> order;`. It is initialized as an empty map. The assignment `order[a]=b;` is a modification *after* initialization, and it is only possible if that line is part of a function body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Am I allow to do that ?"*

Yes of course you can do that (see **[`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)** please). It's perfectly fine (though the parenthesis for `(a)` are superfluous).
The value of `b` will be inserted into the map properly for key `a`, no matter if it existed before (in this case `b` will just replace the already existing associated value).

The case you should take care of is trying to access the `std::map` by key value, without having a value inserted in 1st place, like

```
int storedValue = order[a];
```

In this case a default initialized entry for `order[a]` will be created, and that's not what you want it to be in most of the use cases.

Comment: If you do not want to retrieve a default initialized entry then you should use `std::map::find()` instead of `operator[]`, that way you can handle the case where the key does not exist.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's the conclusion from what I mentioned. I actually retained from bringing in this particular point, because the question wasn't clear about such requirements. But feel free to edit and improve the answer.